# When would you use an edge list graph data structure instead of an adjacency list or adjacency matrix?

Tags: graphs, data-structures

In what applications would you choose an edge list over an adjacency list or an adjacency matrix?

> *Sample Question, VisuAlgo:* Which best graph DS(es) should you use to store a simple undirected graph with 200 vertices, 19900 edges,
> and the edges need to be sorted?
> Suppose your computer only has enough memory to store 40000 entries.

There are three choices: adjacency lists, adjacency matrix, and an **edge list**.

Edge lists are the correct answer here because sorting by weight is most efficient, but what are some other use cases?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean when they say sorted?

Comment: No - I didn't mean that. Especially since graphs usually aren't sorted unless they're trees (in which case I'd just use indexes for min/max heap and binary search).